# PHP How to get HTML elements from start to end?

Tags: php

So what i need to be able to do is that there is file which has html elements like this :

```
    <section class="cta-section section-half">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-9">
                            <h1 class="text-white text-uppercase">Drop us a line</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                            <a class="primary-btn text-uppercase outline-btn" href="#contact-section">Get in touch</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>




 <section class="cta-section section-full">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-9">
                            <h1 class="text-white text-uppercase">Drop us a line</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                            <a class="primary-btn text-uppercase outline-btn" href="#contact-section">Get in touch</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
```

What i want to do it parse the whole page into a array with the elements from start to end

This is what I have been trying:

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($res);

$h2s = $dom->getElementsByTagName('h1');
foreach( $h1s as $h1 ) {
    echo $h1->textContent . "\n";
}
```

but this stripped out all the html which is what i don't want to happen
and it based on get a Tag Name 'h2'

I just want to pass a txt file with html and it turns it into a array with all the code and content in the page

Expected output should look like this

```
array(0 => '<section class="cta-section section-half"> .. all the elements inside ..</section>',
      1 => '<section class="cta-section section-half"> .. all the elements inside ..</section>')
```

if the txt file has a div then the 2 element would be the div with all the content inside

Comment: Can you provide the **exact** expected output from that given input file?

Comment: In your array, you want 1 line = 1 row ?

Comment: _Small Point_ There are no `h2` tags in that file you show us, so I am guessing this is just some random code not really related to the requirement, but you needed some code to avoid the question being so obviously a DIFM

Comment: Maybe if you show us an example of the resulting array you want to achieve it would make the question more clear

Comment: @NicoHaase I have added some more details

Comment: @Lucas Yes with all the html tags with it

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use .innerHTML instead of textContent? AFAIK textcontent omits all html, whereas .innerHTML does not.
Also why not use the section-tag as selector?

Hope i can help

Answer (score 0):

This should do the magic:

```
$h2s = $dom->getElementsByTagName('h2');
foreach( $h2s as $h2 ) {
   echo $dom->saveHTML($h2);
}
```

Or:

```
$h2s = $dom->getElementsByTagName('h2');
foreach( $h2s as $h2 ) {
   echo $h2->innerHTML;
}
```